# Running shell script through oozie

Tags: hadoop, cloud, cloudera, sqoop, oozie

I'm trying to execute a shell script through oozie but I'm having some issues.

I have a property file like this (import.properties):

```
startIndex=2000
chunkSize=2000
```

The idea is, in every single execution the startIndex value will be updated by the chunk size. So if I execute it, it should have

```
startIndex=4000
chunkSize=2000
```

I have tested the script separately and it works fine. Here are my other related files.

job.properties

```
nameNode=hdfs://192.168.56.101:8020
jobTracker=192.168.56.101:50300
wfeRoot=wfe
queueName=default
EXEC=script.sh
propertyLoc=import.properties

oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${wfeRoot}/coordinator
```

workflow.xml

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.2' name='shell-wf'>
<start to='shell1' />
<action name='shell1'>
    <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
              <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
              <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <exec>${EXEC}</exec>
     <file>${EXEC}#${EXEC}</file>
        <file>${propertyLoc}#${propertyLoc}</file>
    </shell>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="fail" />
</action>
<kill name="fail">
    <message>Script failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name='end' />
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
file=import.properties
. $file

SCRIPT=$(readlink -f $file)
SCRIPTPATH=$(dirname $SCRIPT)
echo $SCRIPTPATH

newStartIndex=`expr $chunkSize + $startIndex`
newStartIndexStr=startIndex=$newStartIndex

oldStartIndexStr=startIndex=$startIndex
chunkSizeStr=chunkSize=$chunkSize

sed -i "s|$oldStartIndexStr|$newStartIndexStr|g" $file
```

And I put all these files inside my HDFS working directory:

```
[ambari_qa@sandbox coordinator]$ hadoop fs -lsr /user/ambari_qa/wfe/coordinator
-rw-rw-rw-   1 ambari_qa hdfs         32 2013-05-09 00:12    /user/ambari_qa/wfe/coordinator/import.properties
-rw-rw-rw-   1 ambari_qa hdfs        533 2013-05-09 01:19 /user/ambari_qa/wfe/coordinator/script.sh
-rw-------   1 ambari_qa hdfs        852 2013-05-09 00:50 /user/ambari_qa/wfe/coordinator/workflow.xml
```

I was expecting that the import.properties file will be changed after each execution. But I see it's not changing even though the oozie job is successful. For debugging purpose, I printed out the location of the file during execution and found out that it copied to another location (from log):

```
>>> Invoking Shell command line now >>

Stdoutput /hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/ambari_qa/distcache/-5756672768810005023_889271025_125659265/192.168.56.101/user/ambari_qa/wfe/coordinator
Stdoutput startIndex=4000
Stdoutput startIndex=2000
Exit code of the Shell command 0
<<< Invocation of Shell command completed <<<
```

What I need to do so that it effects the working directory of HDFS? Thanks in advance.

Update:

After changing the script based on Chris's suggestion, it becomes (last 3 lines):

```
hadoop fs -rm hdfs://ip-10-0-0-92:8020/user/ambari_qa/wfe/shell-oozie/$file
sed -i "s|$oldStartIndexStr|$newStartIndexStr|g" $file
hadoop fs -put $file /user/ambari_qa/wfe/shell-oozie
```

But then I started facing permission issue. I gave write permission on that file and folder.

```
[ambari_qa@ip-10-0-0-91 shell-oozie]$  hadoop fs -ls /user/ambari_qa/wfe/shell-oozie
```

Found 3 items:

```
-rw-rw-rw-   3 ambari_qa hdfs         32 2013-05-10 16:55 /user/ambari_qa/wfe/shell-oozie/import.properties
-rw-rw-rw-   3 ambari_qa hdfs        540 2013-05-10 16:48 /user/ambari_qa/wfe/shell-oozie/script.sh
-rw-rw-rw-   3 ambari_qa hdfs        826 2013-05-10 15:29 /user/ambari_qa/wfe/shell-oozie/workflow.xml
```

Here is the error log:

```
rm: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=mapred, access=EXECUTE, inode="ambari_qa":ambari_qa:hdfs:rwxrwx---
put: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=mapred, access=EXECUTE, inode="ambari_qa":ambari_qa:hdfs:rwxrwx---
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.ShellMain], exit code [1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is running on the local distributed cache version of the file - you'll need to pipe the output of sed back via the hadoop fs shell (remembering to delete the file before uploading), something like:

```
hadoop fs -rm /user/ambari_qa/wfe/coordinator/$file

sed "s|$oldStartIndexStr|$newStartIndexStr|g" $file \ 
    hadoop fs -put - /user/ambari_qa/wfe/coordinator/$file
```

There are probably ways you can find the coordinator path in hdfs rather than hard coding it into the script.

**Update**

The permission problem is because the oozie job is running as the mapred user, yet the file only has `rwx` permissions for the user `ambari_qa` and group `hdfs`

```
user=mapred, access=EXECUTE, inode="ambari_qa":ambari_qa:hdfs:rwxrwx---
```

I would either amend the file permissions on the file and parent folder such that the mapred user can delete / replace the file, or look into masquerading as a user that does have the correct permissions

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris for your response. Based on that, I have slightly changed my script

`hadoop fs -rm /user/ambari_qa/wfe/coordinator/$file

sed -i "s|$oldStartIndexStr|$newStartIndexStr|g" $file

hadoop fs -put $file /user/ambari_qa/wfe/coordinator`

But facing permission issue. What should be expected permission on those files which I want to modify through oozie workflow? Thanks again.

Comment: Is the oozie server running as it's own user, and / or do you have user masquerading enabled in HDFS. Basically who owns the file and can you post the full exception message (update your question rather than as a comment)

Comment: Figured out that the parent folder didn't have expected permission. After giving expected permissions, it worked. Thanks a lot again @Chris

Comment: @dreamer Can you please tell me what is the expected permission for the parent folder? I'm facing the same issue too.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem.

I could solve this by adding

`hadoop_user=${2}
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=${hadoop_user}`

hadoop_user is passed as ${wf:user} in the workflow as an argument to the action